# Mobile website subscribe form position

Tags: forms, mobile-web, popup, infinite-scroll, subscription

I'm developing (and designing) a products showcase website with mobile-first approach. My company needs a form for users to subscribe to our newsletter.

My main problem is that so far my design use infinite scroll (drag to top to show more items - something like that) to show the products so I think there is no way to put my subscribe form to the footer. I'm thinking of using pop-up/modal form but I afraid it would be annoying. I wonder if there are any other way to achieve this.

Thank you, any help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: imgur creates several sizes for each image, so once you upload one you can simply add letter "l" for large, "m" for medium, etc in the end of the file name: xxxxxl.jpg

Comment: you’re welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can fix a button to the bottom of the mobile layout and scroll behind it, whether it's the best method to use is tough to say without seeing at least a wireframe or prototype.

If you do have a button to subscribe, which takes the user out of the flow of the items you are listing, I would ensure you make it easy for them to return to the same place once subscribed or not.

Comment: Actually I already have a sticky footer (for filtering the product). Is it save to put another sticky element on top of it? It can be dismissed with close button of course. Or is it fine to put it below the sticky navbar? Thank you :)

Comment: Again it's tough to say without seeing the layout, however it sounds like you would be either confusing the layout as the subscribe doesn't relate to the content you are displaying and you already have buttons to provide function in the location you are suggesting. Any chance you could post a screenshot?

Comment: Edited my post :) I also have a collapsible sticky footer to put product comparison (this is very important and should be put this way). If you want to see the website here it is [link](http://rosiana.github.io/cm) but please only on mobile view. Many many thanks!